# O que o "return" faz em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

O que "realmente" o `return` faz em Python, principalmente em funções recursivas. Ex. fatorial:

```
def fatorial(n):
    if n==1:
        return n
    return fatorial(n-1) * n
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 16):

Como em qualquer linguagem *mainstream*, o `return` encerra a execução da função corrente, voltando exatamente para o ponto onde ela foi chamada.

Eventualmente ele poderá devolver um valor como resultado da função, ou seja, onde a função foi chamada terá o valor de retorno usado na expressão ali construída.

Não tem nada de especial no `return` quando é usado em funções recursivas, o funcionamento é exatamente o mesmo. Em uma função recursiva as chamadas vão se acumulando e os retornos vão ocorrendo depois voltando sempre para o mesmo ponto, mas em estados diferentes. Obviamente em algum momento precisa parar de fazer chamadas recursivas, sob pena de ter uma recursividade infinita e estourar a pilha.

Como não é um caso especial, se houver uma quantidade grande de chamadas, e cada chamada vai mantendo seu próprio estado (valores das variáveis locais), vai enchendo a [pilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) da aplicação e poderá dar o tal do *stack overflow*.

Algumas linguagens/compiladores fazem otimizações para evitar esse estouro em casos de muita recursão, o que também ajuda na eficiência.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não qualquer linguagem: http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/cf2d84d26824491585256c54004c65c5?OpenDocument . Talvez qualquer linguagem que se preze. =/

Comment: Ah, as *mainstream*, né? :)

Answer (score 4):

Ele retorna o valor da função. No caso específico de funções recursivas, ele, além de retornar o valor (que também pode ser um valor nulo `None`), também irá retornar o fluxo de controle para a função de chamadora.

Comment: O retorno do fluxo de controle para a função chamadora acontece mesmo em funções não-recursivas.