# Return em python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou criando uma função em python3 e surgiu uma dúvida sobre o uso do return, 
quando chamamos ele no código ele deve encerrar a função imediatamente?

No código abaixo isso não está funcionando, mesmo quando o if é satisfeito, ele termina o loop inteiro do código, para depois dar o retorno.

```
def find_msg_by_parameter(parameter, search_term, email_folder):
    client = client_connect()
    results = client.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds = [email_folder]).execute()
    for id_mail in results['messages']:
        id_msg = client.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=id_mail['id']).execute()
        id_msg_df = pd.DataFrame(id_msg['payload']['headers'])
        msg_header = id_msg_df[id_msg_df.name==parameter].value.iloc[0]
        if check_name(search_term,msg_header):
            return id_mail
        print('Buscando')
    print('Não encontrado')
```

A função check_name retorna um booleano.

Answer (score 2):

O return [encerra a execução da função corrente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115335/o-que-o-return-faz-em-python).

Faça algum teste para ver o comportamento do return.. Por exemplo:

```
def test_return(var1, var2):
    print("Entrou")
    if var1 < var2:
        return "Menor"
    else:
        print("Maior")
    print("Depois do if")
    return "Saiu"

print(test_return(1, 2))
print("\n Chama a funcao novamente: \n")
print(test_return(3, 2))
```

Comment: Consegui descobrir qual era o problema, a lista que é iterada é gerada com ordenação aleatória, o return estava funcionando corretamente, eu que não me atentei a este detalhe. Obrigado!