# Como retirar números repetidos de uma lista em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Olá galera tô fazendo um curso de python e atualmente eu empaquei nesse exercício.

Escreva a função remove_repetidos que recebe como parâmetro uma lista com números inteiros, verifica se tal lista possui elementos repetidos e os remove. A função deve devolver uma lista correspondente à primeira lista, sem elementos repetidos. A lista devolvida deve estar ordenada.

Se alguém puder dá uma dica ou uma solução fico grato

```
numeros = (input("Digite uma lista com números inteiros: "))
list = numeros.split()   # transforma em listas

print("Você digitou os seguintes números: ")
print(list)

def remove_repetidos(list):

    sorted(set(list)) # ordena e une todos os números em vez de tá repetido, somente haverá um número representando o conjunto "set"
    print("O resultado é")
    print()
    print( sorted(set(list)))

remove_repetidos(list)
```

Comment: Qual a sua duvida, fiz um teste e sua função removeu os duplicados e ordenou... Ela não está de fato retornando, mas parte do código está funcionando.

Comment: Olá eu digito uma lista por exemplo `[1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,44,4,4,4,4,4]` e ele me retorna a mesma lista em vez de retornar `[1,2,4,44]`

Answer (score 4):

```
numeros = (input("Digite uma lista com números inteiros: "))
lista = numeros.split()   # transforma em listas

print("Você digitou os seguintes números: ")
print(lista)


def remove_repetidos(lista):

  lista_numeros_unicos = []

  for numero in lista:
    if(numero in lista_numeros_unicos): #Verifica se o atual elemento existe na lista original
      pass #Se existir não faz nada
    else:
      lista_numeros_unicos.append(numero) #Se não existir, adiciona com o comando append() o numero na lista

  return lista_numeros_unicos

# Ordena a lista
lista = sorted(remove_repetidos(lista))

print("\n A lista sem numeros repetidos é: ")
print(lista)
```

Basicamente você precisa só criar uma lista auxiliar, que no caso foi a `lista_numeros_unicos`, ela recebe, os números não repetidos que estão na lista. Perceba que utilizei o operador `in`.

**Obs:** `list` é uma palavra reservada, tome cuidado.

[Link para teste em compilador online, Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/AdmirableAttractiveRam)

Comment: Muito brigado pela resposta entendi muito bem o que vc expressou e gostei da sua observação :) , porém não funfou eu digitei `[1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,44,4,4,4,4,4]` e tive como retorno `['[1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,44,4,4,4,4,4]']` sendo que era pra ter como retorno `[1,2,4]`

Comment: Isso acontece porque você está digitando as vírgulas, o que torna um único elemento, por exemplo, '2,2,3,5,2,2' ao invés de '2','2','3','5','2','2', se utilizar apenas espaço, ele vai funcionar corretamente. Todavia se precisar digitar as vírgulas, posso ver se consigo alterar o código.

Comment: Aceito a ajuda :) com o código com a digitação das vírgulas.E u tentei outras formas e o código antigo pegou normalmente sem vírgulas, mas como é preciso não consegui fazer :(

Answer (score 1):

A sua função está ordenando a lista e removendo os números repetidos perfeitamente. O que você precisa fazer agora é apenas utilizar o [`return`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115347/157404) para retornar a nova lista.

```
def remove_repetidos(list_):
    return sorted(set(list_))

number_list = [7, 1, 2, 8, 5, 1, 7, 2, 8]
new_list = remove_repetidos(number_list)
```

Comment: Olá continua retornando o mesmo valor

Comment: `def remove_repetidos(lista):`

    `return sorted(set(lista)) 
    number_list= lista
    nova_lista = remove_repetidos(number_list)
    print("O resultado é")
    print()
    print( sorted(set(lista)))

remove_repetidos(lista)`

Answer (score 1):

```
# se utilizar as duas funções abaixo, que funcionam como decoradores...

def remove_espacos_de_cada_elemento_em_uma_lista_de_strings(func):
    def remover_espacos(lista):
        nova_lista = [x.strip() for x in lista]
        return func(nova_lista)
    return remover_espacos


def remove_elementos_repetidos_em_uma_lista(func):
        def filtrar(lista):
            for i in lista:
                if lista.count(i) > 1:
                   lista.remove(i)
                   filtrar(lista)
            return lista

        def lista_com_elementos_unicos(lista):
            lista_unica = filtrar(lista)
            return func(lista_unica)

        return lista_com_elementos_unicos

#### poderá decorar qualquer função e ter o retorno de qualquer objeto, com elementos únicos(lista, tuplas, dicionários...)
```

Exemplo:

```
@remove_espacos_de_cada_elemento_em_uma_lista_de_strings
def retirar_espacos_de_cada_elemento_em_uma_lista_de_strings(lista):
    return lista
```

Comment: Valeu pela contribuição, porém não funcionou :(

Answer (score 1):

Lendo os comentários entendi o que está acontecendo, ao digitar a lista você usa a própria sintaxe de lista literal python para inseri-la como entrada e as resposta usam uma sintaxe de lista cujo os itens são separados por espaço e a entrada não e delimitada por colchetes.

Portanto não vou me deter a função `remove_repetidos()` pois as outras repostas já explanaram o assunto e então vou defini-lá duma maneira que visualmente passe despercebida:

```
remove_repetidos = lambda l: list(sorted(set(l)))
```

Vou me focar mais no tratamento da entrada pelo console.
Tomemos três entradas:

- `[3,2,5,2,4,0,5,2,3]`
- `3,2,5,2,4,0,5,2,3`
- `3 2 5 2 4 0 5 2 3`

De apenas olhar podemos concluir:

1. Todas essas entradas podem ser compreendidas como sendo uma lista digitada pelo usuário.
2. Elas podem ou não serem iniciadas e finalizadas por colchetes `[]`.
3. O conteúdo que importa são os seus elementos numéricos e não os separadores.

Ciente disso podemos tratar a entrada do usuário removendo tudo aquilo que não é numérico e aproveitando esse caracteres não numéricos para agrupar os algarismos e assim separar os números para os recompormos uma lista de inteiros.

Para remover o que não é numérico e separar a entrada em strings numéricas usei uma [Expressão Regular](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) e método `re.split()` que divide uma string pelas ocorrências de um padrão.
O padrão utilizado foi `(?a)\D+` onde:
 - **(?a)** equivale a constante [re.ASCII](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.ASCII) que força ao padrão **\D** a captura ASCII.
 - **\D+** significa capturar um ou mais de tudo aquilo que não for um dígito ASCII.

Para remover as capturas vazias que podem ser geradas por separadores duplicados ou separadores presentes no inicio e no fim da entrada usei a função built-in [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) com objeto [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/none.html) como parâmetro de filtragem.
Para converter as strings numéricas em inteiros usei a função built-in [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) para aplicar o constructor da classe `int` a cada elemento anteriormente retornado por `filter()`.

```
import re

numeros = input("Digite uma lista com números inteiros: ")

#Cria uma lista de inteiros apartando as strings numérica de 
#tudo aquilo que não for número decimal
lista = list(map(int, filter(None, re.split('(?a)\D+', numeros ))))

print("Você digitou os seguintes números: ")
print(lista)

#Cria a função remove_repetidos que cria e ordena um set a #partir de uma lista
remove_repetidos = lambda l: list(sorted(set(l)))

print("Sua lista filtrada e ordenada: ")
print(remove_repetidos(lista))
```

Teste o código no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/WickedMintcreamDaemon

Exemplo de saída:

```
Digite uma lista com números inteiros: [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,44,4,4,4,4,4]
Você digitou os seguintes números: 
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 44, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
Sua lista filtrada e ordenada: 
[1, 2, 4, 44]
```

Exemplo de saída:

```
Digite uma lista com números inteiros: 7 6 7 6 5 8 9
Você digitou os seguintes números: 
[7, 6, 7, 6, 5, 8, 9]
Sua lista filtrada e ordenada: 
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esta questão devemos seguir as seguintes etapas:

1. Capturar os valores;
2. Armazena-los em uma lista;
3. Passar esta lista como argumento para a função `remove_repetidos()`;
4. Remover os valores repetidos;
5. Exibir a lista sem os valores repetidos.

Então, desenvolvi o seguinte script:

```
def remove_repetidos(lis):
    li_sem_repeticoes = list()
    for item in lis:
        if item not in li_sem_repeticoes:
            li_sem_repeticoes.append(item)
    return li_sem_repeticoes


lista = list(map(int, input('Digite os valores da lista: ').split()))

print(f'\033[32mA lista sem repetições é:\n{remove_repetidos(lista)}\033[m')
```

Observe que quando executamos este script recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite os valores da lista:` . Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores da lista, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`.

Depois da inserção dos valores o script pegará os valores digitados e montará uma lista. Em seguida, esta lista é enviada como `argumento` para a função `remove_repetidos`. Chegando lá, o bloco `for` percorrerá a lista alvo passando por todos elementos. Durante cada uma das passagens (interações), é verificada se o elemento da vez está contido na lista `li_sem_repeticoes`. Caso negativo, o referido elemento é adicionado na lista `li_sem_repeticoes` e posteriormente exibirá a mesma ordenada em forma crescente.

**Exemplo 1**

Se digitarmos...

```
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4 4 44 4 4 4 4 4
```

... e pressionarmos `enter`, teremos as seguinte saídas...

```
A lista sem repetições é:
[1, 2, 4, 44]
```

Observe que no **exemplo 1** foram digitados **22** elementos, além disso, o 17º elemento desta lista é **44**. Este elemento só ocorre **1** só vez na referida lista. Por isso, este elemento é exibido na lista original sem repetições.

**Exemplo 2**

Se digitarmos...

```
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

...e pressionarmos `enter`, teremos as seguintes saídas...

```
A lista sem repetições é:
[1, 2, 4]
```

Observe que no **exemplo 2** foram digitados **21** elementos, além disso, não existe algum elemento **44**. Por isto, a lista original sem repetições não possui o elemento **44**.

Answer (score 0):

```
numeros = input("Digite uma lista com números inteiros: ")
lista = numeros.split()   # transforma em listas

print("Você digitou os seguintes números: ")
print(lista)

def remove_repetidos(lista_qualquer):
    lista_sem_elementos_repetidos = [] 
    lista_qualquer.sort() # ordena a lista_qualquer
    for numero in lista_qualquer: 
        if numero not in lista_sem_elementos_repetidos: # Se o número não estiver na lista
            lista_sem_elementos_repetidos.append(numero) # Adiciona o número a lista
    return lista_sem_elementos_repetidos # Retorna a lista_sem_elementos_repetidos

print(remove_repetidos(lista))
```

Comment: Por que ordenar a lista de entrada ao invés da lista final?

Comment: Não poste apenas código sem explicar o propósito, a estratégia, ideia, e assim por diante

Answer (score -3):

Utilizando sets (conjuntos), desenvolver um código em Python que recebe números ou palavras (strings), avisando quando houver tentativa de inserção de elemento repetido. Inicialmente, o usuário escolhe quantos elementos o conjunto irá guardar e se os elementos serão números ou palavras (que deverão ser testados antes de serem inseridos no conjunto). No final, imprimir o conjunto e a quantidade de tentativas de inserções repetidas não válidas. As variáveis, estruturas de dados e funções devem possuir nomes e sobrenomes do(s) aluno(s) (do grupo).