# Loop "For" dentro de uma função não dá o mesmo resultado que usado fora

Tags: python, funções, for

Estou tentando criar uma função, onde a mesma lê os dados de um arquivo `.txt` e me retorna eles, porém ao criar o código dentro de uma função o mesmo me retorna apenas a primeira linha:

```
def ler_dados():
    with open('CTE_ARBA.txt', 'r') as arq:
        dados = arq.readlines()
        for linhas in dados:
            return linhas 

print(ler_dados())
output: 15211030800078000151570010000
```

Quando faço o mesmo código, porem fora de uma função, ele me retorna todos os valores do arquivo.

E possível criar função que me retorne todos os valores?

Comment: O `return` [encerra a execução da função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115335/112052), e vc faz isso logo na primeira iteração. Se quer retornar tudo, tire o `for` e faça apenas `return dados`

Answer (score 4):

O `return` serve para devolver um resultado para a função, e interromper o fluxo, portanto a função encerra quando encontra este comando.

Tenho algumas soluções:

1. Faça a impressão dentro da função e só retorne ao final dela, não dentro do laço (pode até deixar o retorno implícito). Mas isso não tem separação de responsabilidade, só pode imprimir no console, não poderá reaproveitar a função para outras coisas, e pode não ser o que deseja.
2. Crie uma lista de dados e retorne-a. Aí quem chamou pega essa lista retorna e faz um laço para imprimir cada elemento. Isso é o ideal na maioria das situações. Note que `dados` já é uma lista pronta para retornar, então só crie outra se quer algum formato diferente.
3. Retorne um iterador e assim vai pegando cada um dos elementos por vez dentro de um laço. Isso é feito com o [comando `yield`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92921/101) em vez do `return`. Ele controla a passagem em cada um dos elementos. Pode ver mais no *link* fornecido.

Algo assim:

```
def ler_dados():
    with open('CTE_ARBA.txt', 'r') as arq:
        dados = arq.readlines()
        for linha in dados:
            yield linha

for linha in ler_dados():
    print(linha)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Function/Yield.py).

Comment: Maniero, entendi ficou baste claro, sempre que utilizar um return vai interromper o fluxo da função, quebrando assim o loop feito dentro dele. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Se resolveu você pode marcar a resposta com correta, veja o sinal verdinho ali do lado da resposta logo abaixo do placar. Depois se tiver mais votos pode votar também.

Answer (score 3):

Apenas como complemento da resposta do Maniero, você não precisa trazer todo o conteúdo para a memória usando o `readlines()` para depois iterá-las e retorná-las na função.

Com o `yield from` você pode subdelegar a responsabilidade de gerar os valores diretamente para o manipulador de arquivos, assim ele lê linha a linha já retornando para você na função, mantendo apenas uma linha em memória por vez.

```py
def ler_dados():
    with open('CTE_ARBA.txt', 'r') as stream:
        yield from stream

for linha in ler_dados():
    print(linha)
```

Comment: Possivelmente poderia fazer apenas `yield from open(...)`, mas não estou lembrado como ele trataria a abertura do arquivo nessa situação. Provavelmente teria o mesmo efeito, pois o arquivo seria fechado quando a função `ler_dados` fosse encerrada devido ao contexto.